# InvalidSelectorError, need help defining my xpath selector

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, dom, xpath

I'm looking at a giant dom tree. Using NodeJS/Selenium, I specifically need to find by title in the a tag, and I need to click the href associated. I'm very new to regex and am getting lots of errors already.

Here is my best attempt so far:

```
By.xpath(//ul/class='slds-grid'//a[title="${uniqueStringToMatch}"]).click()
```

Getting

> InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression //ul/class='slds-grid slds-grid--pull-padded slds-wrap
>   list'//a[text()="Load Client Referrals"] because of the following
>   error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': Type
>   conversion failed while evaluating the expression.

The following tree leaves out all the hierarchy that lies above, as I don't think it's important, but correct me if I'm wrong. From the first unique className in the tree...

```
    <ul class='slds-grid'>
        <li class='slds-col'>
            <a class="app_launcher" href="thelinkIwantToclick" title="uniqueStringToMatch"
                <span class="label-ctr">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class='slds-col'>
            <a class="app_launcher" href="thelinkIwantToclick" title="uniqueStringToMatch"
                <span class="label-ctr">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class='slds-col'>
            <a class="app_launcher" href="thelinkIwantToclick" title="uniqueStringToMatch"
                <span class="label-ctr">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

All titles within the li are unique.

I'm using W3 schools to learn, but running out of time here.

(I'm also in search of the quickest way to write xpath on my own - tools or tutorials would be much appreciated!)

Comment: @Mark Now I'm using this:  //ul[@class="slds-grid"]/li/a[@title="uniqueStringToMatch"]      I get a new error:  NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='slds-grid slds-grid--pull-padded slds-wrap list']/li/a[@title="Accounts"]"}        I verified this is perfect xpath with Chrome Xpath Helper plugin

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to test it just now, but I usually use the @ syntax to match attributes in XPath. Would something like this work for you?

```
By.xpath("//ul[@class='slds-grid']//a[@title='${uniqueStringToMatch}']").click()
```

I've also found it hard to find beginner-level tutorials for simple XPath, and ended up learning a lot by trial and error. There's also an extension for Chrome and Firefox which generates XPath strings for elements in web pages, and I learned a lot from that.

Comment: No luck yet. I also tried adding /.. to the end, but same error.                      By.xpath(`//ul/class='slds-grid'//a[@title="${page}"]/..`).click()

Comment: updated dom tree above to reflect the actual architecture

Comment: //ul[@class="slds-grid slds-grid--pull-padded slds-wrap list"]/li/a[@title="${page}"]

Answer (score 2):

You could do a lot worse than reading the W3C XPath 1.0 specification: it's surprisingly short and readable, compared with later specs

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Certainly, you will save an immense amount of time compared with trying to learn by trial and error or by copying-and-pasting examples. Though of course everyone has their own learning styles.

But when I see something like

```
//ul/class='slds-grid'//a[title="${uniqueStringToMatch}"]
```

I just wonder what on earth you were thinking: you clearly haven't grasped the core concepts of paths and steps.

There are two basic operations in XPath.

- A/B means find the things selected by A, and starting from there, then find the things selected by B.
- A[P] means find the things selected by A, and then eliminate those that don't match the condition P.

Your `class='slds-grid'` is clearly meant to be a filter condition, and (since class and title are attributes rather than elements) it should therefore be

```
//ul[@class='slds-grid']//a[@title="${uniqueStringToMatch}"]
```

Incidentally, XPath has almost nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the tough love :) Since my original post, I came to the following:    Now I'm using this: //ul[@class="slds-grid"]/li/a[@title="uniqueStringToMatch"] I get a new error: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='slds-grid slds-grid--pull-padded slds-wrap list']/li/a[@title="Accounts"]"} I verified this is perfect xpath with Chrome Xpath Helper plugin –

Comment: Tried your xpath, same error. Makes sense, as I'm learning //a does the same thing as /li/a (which I did read about high level on W3)

Comment: I should mention, I am using this notation "${uniqueStringToMatch}"

Comment: It seems very odd to me that the XPath expression in the error message is different from the expression you say you are using. But that's something specific to your code or your XPath engine or API, so I can't help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

//ul[@class="slds-grid"]//a[@title="uniqueStringToMatch"]

Comment: Thank you both: Michael and Mark!